# UWP: `webview` contents cut off if window is resized

Tags: windows, visual-studio, c#-4.0, uwp

I want to resize webview with window.
But, when I reduce the size of the window, the webview is cut off.
(When I grow the size of the window it looks normal.)

```html
    <Grid>
        <WebView x:Name="m_WebView" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="350" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="568" ScriptNotify="m_WebView_ScriptNotify" NavigationCompleted="m_WebView_OnNavigationCompleted" x:FieldModifier="public"/>
        <ProgressRing x:Name="workingProgressRing" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="50" Height="50"/>

    </Grid>
```

```js
        private void Page_onSizeChanged2(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
        {

            double widthRatio = e.NewSize.Width / (double)568;
            double heightRatio = e.NewSize.Height / (double)320;
            double newRatio = widthRatio < heightRatio ? widthRatio : heightRatio;
            double newWidth = 568 * newRatio;
            double newHeight = 320 * newRatio;

            m_WebView.RenderTransform = new CompositeTransform { ScaleX = newRatio, ScaleY = newRatio };

            ((CompositeTransform)m_WebView.RenderTransform).TranslateX = -(newWidth - 568 * widthRatio) / 2;
            ((CompositeTransform)m_WebView.RenderTransform).TranslateY = -(newHeight - 320 * heightRatio) / 2;


        }
```

[Normal window picture.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RonYO.png)

[Cut off webview picture.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lNV4D.png)

Comment: How can I reduce the size together? Help me..

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to size controls in UWP is scaling the automatically based on the layout instead of directly hardcoding `Width` and `Height` values.

In your case you could remove the `Width` and `Height` attributes, set `HorizontalAlignment` and `VerticalAlignment` to `Stretch` and let the `WebView` scale with the `Grid` instead.